# Link to slide in Double Carousel slide show

Tags: slideshow, carousel

I want to create a link in a Double Carousel slide show.
the following example:

http://demo.owwwlab.com/wp-toranj

For example, there are bullets on the right side when I click on one of them  I move to another slide in the slide show.
How do I create a link from another page with JS into one of the slide in the slide show?

Thanks for help

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified which plugin you used for the solution at hand, or if you wrote this by yourself.

Comment: I dont use plugin, its only html and JS